# Continuity with respect to the definite topology. Examples and applications

Tags: general-topology, continuity

So I understand with respect to cofinite topology if a given function is continuous, every closed set is closed in its preimage. But How do I apply that to show a function is continuous?

So for example given $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R},\:f(x)=x^{2}$

I'm trying to show $f$ is continuous with respect to cofinite topology. I understand that all I need to do is given any $C$ closed its preimage is closed but given $C$ it is some finite set.

Comment: I presume you meant "every closed set has closed preimage", rather than "every closed set is closed in its preimage".

Comment: It does not change much, materially, but are you asking for continuity with respect to cofinite topology both in the domain and the codomain- say $f:\Bbb R_{\text{cof}}\to\Bbb R_{\text{cof}}$?

Comment: In cofinite topology a subset $A\subseteq X$ is closed in $X$ if and only if it is either finite or $A=X$. Thus if both $\mathbb{R}$ are equiped with cofinite topology then all you have to do is to show that the preimage of a finite set is either finite or whole $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: I guess I'm really weak at the examples. How would I show a finite set in the image? and how do I take a preimage of that? I can take an example of a finite closed set and show that preimage is finite, but I'm having trouble with the general notion.